# Setting up NAT with firewall for RDP connection

Tags: firewalls, rdp, nat

I have a vendor who needs to connect remotely to one of our servers. What I thought I would do is setup a NAT rule in our firewall. I have a public IP address that I will have translated to the local server address so that then the vendor just needs to RDP to the public IP address. Is this a secure way to have the vendor connect? I can restrict the service to port 3389 and set the source IP address to only accept the vendor's public IP address.[image]

Comment: Setting IP restrictions on the incoming traffic would be helpful but I'd also go another step further and change the port to a non-standard port to avoid extra traffic from port scans.  Since 3389 is a known service port for RDP it is more likely to be in port scan lists than something like 48399.  You should be able to translate the port from the non-standard to 3389 on inbound traffic and the reverse of that going out to avoid having to reconfigure your server for all RDP traffic.

Comment: And if you're very concerned about security create a limited user account in AD that only had rights on that server... but that's not a Network Engineering question.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Source address restriction is a good idea if your vendor use static IP addresses.
Btw, as Mike Naylor mentioned, you should translate to non-standard port instead of 3389 to prevent insider threats from your vendor.
The last point is you can limit connection rate to prevent brute-force or flood attacks even when attacker know the service's port.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in 'insider threats from your vendor' as his question is specifically asking how to give vendor access, they will need the port number regardless.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, regarding "insider threats from your vendor" I mean one of their machines could be compromised and infected malware that automate scanning or looking for other machine on standard ports (e.g 22 for *nix, 3389 for Windows) to detect it was Linux/Windows machine and making their way to attack then.